# VS2017 Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime after using "Open Folder"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#

I have a visual studio (F#) project that was previously working in Visual Studio, and still runs fine via command like `dotnet run`.

However, after I moved it into a new folder, and opened that folder with Visual Studio (File -> Open Folder), I am getting the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I'm not sure why Visual Studio has started giving this error when I try to run/debug the project, because I don't believe I make any references to it.

If I open the solution/project file in Visual Studio normally debugging works just fine. The issue is trying to open the parent folder and running the project from there.

Comment: The Open Folder experience for F# (and largely .NET) is not the same as the solution/project experience. It's mostly just for quickly looking at code and making tiny edits without a fully-formed experience in place.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I was able to get my desired workflow (working on both the F# server project and Vue.js client project with one VS2017 instance) by moving the Vue.js project into a subfolder of the F# project.